# index empty buffer PFQuery - string Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, initialization

I am relatively new to Swift and iOS programming so I don't know why my string isn't working. Whenever I run a println for any index of the string, I get an index empty buffer error. This uses Parse and is querying an object on the server.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

 var wordString = [String]()


 func CallData() {
     var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "example class")
     query.whereKey("example type", equalTo: "example category")
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
         if error == nil {
             println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
             if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                 for object in objects {
                     self.wordString.append(object["Word"] as String)
                 }
             }
         } else {
             println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
         }
     }
 }



 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     CallData()
     println(wordString[0])
 }



 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is undefined or empty or client will crash trying to print it.

```
let = object["Word"] as String {
   self.wordString.append(newObject)

}
```

This is basically try catch block of swift